# possible inconsistency in constant values?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

In the code below `p` is constant both the pointer and value but `b` can change the value of `*p`. It is not intuitive. Shouldn't the compiler produce a warning at least?

```
int b{3}
const int* const p{&b}
//*p = 5;  // correctly produces error
b = 5;     // constant value is changed
cout << *p << endl; // shows 5.
```

Comment: What gives you the impression `int b{3}` makes up a constant value? It's just an initialization.

Comment: Did your code compile? Please copy the code from your editor and paste it here, do not type it again because it might contain errors that are not in your original code.

Comment: Also `const` doesn't really mean the value is constant, it means the compiler will prevent you from changing it unless you explicitly force the change, besides that `p` is `const` but `b` isn't.

Comment: @iharob, this code compiles in my ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is not declared `const` so you can change it all you want.

Just because you declared a `const` pointer to a `const int` doesn't mean that the `int` itself actually has to be declared `const`.

For example, consider this example.

```
int foo(int const& x)    // In the context of this function x is const
{
    return x + 5;
}
```

Then

```
int a = 3;        // Note, this is not const
int b = foo(a);
a += 6;           // This is fine!
```

In the above example `a` is not `const` but was passed into a function as a `const&`. So as long as you don't try to modify `x` within `foo` you did nothing wrong. But you can modify `a` back outside of `foo`.